# C# Dropdown Slide Form

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, slide

Is there any built-in control like a dropdown/slider? For instance, I want to display some info on dialog/control/form and inside that form there is a arrow which expands it to show more information?

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/4945/73068794.jpg](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/4945/73068794.jpg)

When I click the black arrow, the form should expand vertically to show more info. That's what I want to achieve. If there isn't any built-in control, can you please tell me what do I need to do to implement it myself? And how can I add a little animation when it is expanding?

Like [here](http://www.obout.com/sm3/pro_5.aspx) (when you click the menu header it doesn't expand/contract instantly rather it does little slowly, that's the kind of animation I would like to add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/TgXPPanel.aspx) should help you get started.

Comment: Though there is no animation but that still does my job. Thanks